# Opening a subwindow as part of the MainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop

## Overview

Hey everyone, I'm working on a project that is a C# WPF desktop app to create and edit a complex system. Simply think of it as and editor that can put together a full description of a car with all it's subcomponents.
I want each different component of the car to have a separate editor window. Like select the painting on the car and tada a sidewindow appears where you can fully customize the car's paint. Then when you click on the engine, that same sidewindow get's replaced by a new editor about the car's engine.

## Question

How can I make that editor window that I already created with xaml and codebehind to appear as a part of the MainWindow, embedded as a sidebar?
If possible, I would avoid any 3rd party libraries, but if there is no other 'clean' way of doing it then I'm open to suggestions in that area as well.

I have fully functional windows that I created with the designer, wrote all the code for it to work, now I just have to find a way to embed those into the MainWindow on a press of a button.

*Thanks for any answers*

Comment: A `Window` is a standalone frame and cannot be embedded into another `Window`. You should be able to migrate your XAML and codebehind to a [`UserControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=net-5.0) which [can be used](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/) in the XAML of your `Window`.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to "part of the MainWindow", you should not create another *window* because a `Window` cannot be a child of another element.

What you probably want to do is to move the XAML markup and code-behind from your current subwindow into a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). You can then put the `UserControl`(s) into an appropriate [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) in your `MainWindow`.

For example, if you want `UserControl` to appear a sidebar in the window, you could use a `DockPanel` to dock it to the right:

```
<DockPanel>

    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Yellow">
        <local:SidebarUserControl Margin="10" />
    </Border>

    <TextBlock>main content...</TextBlock>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Already started working on the changes.